# How to make Scriptable Objects derive from other Gameobejcts?

Tags: unity, c#, inheritance

I encountered a problem where I want to make a Scriptable Object that derives from another class, but C# does not support multiple inheritance. Further, I do not think it would not make sense to make interfaces for this example. There is a lot of duplicate code within methods that only an abstract class could contain implementations of.

Basically, I want an abstract class that models "anything that can take a turn." I call it a TurnTakeable. But I also want the TurnTakeable to be split into friend and foe derived types, as the two are slightly different. Yet they mostly have the same behavior.

Is there a workaround, or do I have to make an interface? :(

Comment: Any reason things can't be split into components?

Comment: @Sidar, could you be more specific?

Comment: You're using unity and you want to your objects to have certain functionality. Can you not split them up in components rather than a inheritance tree?

Comment: I'm new to this concept. Can you give an example?

Comment: It makes sense to me that a "thing that can take a turn" is a Scriptable Object. Further, I want those things to be able to have some shared functionality like take a turn, die, attack, defend, etc.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it.

Comment: "Thing that can take a turn" so you're speaking of some sort of system/manager? But then you also imply individual objects need to take control as well. It's not very clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

I decided to make the abstract class the scriptable object.

Comment: You'd have to show more for an answer than this. This won't help other people.